# Does a poor mobile network signal cause faster battery drain?

Tags: signal, network, mobile

Quite a simple question actually, does a poor mobile network signal cause faster battery drain?

If so, is there a difference between 2g/3g/4g/5g in the speed at which the battery drains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's having a poor link back to the tower that does you in.  Cell phones (and towers) interactively adjust their transmit levels to be just good enough for solid reception.  So there's a command from the tower to the phone that pretty much boils down to "speak up, sonny!", but is probably named something boring like "transmit power command".

It's hard to talk about battery draining speed for each of the different services -- as time goes on, the protocols become more demanding, but all the technology around them gets advanced.  I can't say for sure, but if the 5G designers are smart, they're thinking about handpiece power drain as they're designing their system.

Comment: I think it is less a command as that the cell sends a feedback message.  "Too many errors in received messages" and the phones decide how to react.  May even be a negotiation - tower says "bad reception," phone says "I'm at full power, is there a better channel to use," tower says "switch to channel X, there's less traffic there "

Answer (score 4):

> Quite a simple question actually, does a poor mobile network signal
>   cause faster battery drain?

Yes, the problem is three fold:

- The phone needs to use more CPU and radio resources to establish a link
- A poor signal corresponds to higher packet loss. Whenever loss occurs packets are re-sent. This means more energy is expended to resend the lost packets.
- Radios will increase their power to compensate, this means more power will be used.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a difference between 2g/3g/4g/5g in the speed at which the battery drains.

Most certainly, and it should be obvious for you when comparing an old Nokia GSM (2/3G) feature phone standby time, to the standby time of a 4/5G phone. The former can easily last for 1-2 weeks. But there are obviously many other things that draw power.

One of the most notable reasons for power consumption is the difference of spectral energy. Because 4G (and in particular 5G) is using a relatively wide spectrum and larger number of channels as compared to 2G, it will need more energy to support those.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile phones uses power when it updates the network on it´s location, and when it listens to the network to see if there is any messages to it. The algoritms to do this are better in the later systems, so they consume less power for this.
But if you co-locate a computer in the phone that contantly sends and receive data to and from the network you can understand why a modern phone has a shorter battery life than the old Nokia one.